# how to apply font properties on <span> while passing html to pdf using itextsharp

Tags: html, pdf, itext

I am converting html to pdf using itextsharp and I want to set the font size for  tags. How can I do this?

Currently I am using:

**StyleSheet**

```
styles = new StyleSheet();
styles.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.SPAN, HtmlTags.FONTSIZE, "9f");
string contents = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/PDF TEMPLATES/DeliveryNote.html"));
```

**List**

```
parsedHtmlElements = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(contents), styles);
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constants listed in `HtmlTags` are actually a hodgepodge of HTML tags and HTML and CSS properties and values and it can be a little tricky sometimes figuring out what to use.

In your case try `HtmlTags.SIZE` instead of `HtmlTags.FONTSIZE` and you should get what you want.

**EDIT**

I've never really seen a good tutorial on what properties do what, I usually just go directly to the source code. For instance, in the [`ElementFactory`](http://itextsharp.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/itextsharp/trunk/src/core/iTextSharp/text/html/simpleparser/ElementFactory.cs?revision=285&view=markup) class there's a method called [`GetFont()`](http://itextsharp.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/itextsharp/trunk/src/core/iTextSharp/text/html/simpleparser/ElementFactory.cs?revision=285&view=markup#l94) that shows how font information is parsed. Specifically on [line 130](http://itextsharp.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/itextsharp/trunk/src/core/iTextSharp/text/html/simpleparser/ElementFactory.cs?revision=285&view=markup#l130) (of revision 229) you'll see where the `HtmlTags.SIZE` is used. However, the actual value for the size is parsed in [`ChainedProperties`](http://itextsharp.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/itextsharp/trunk/src/core/iTextSharp/text/html/simpleparser/ChainedProperties.cs?revision=285&view=markup) in a method called [`AdjustFontSize()`](http://itextsharp.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/itextsharp/trunk/src/core/iTextSharp/text/html/simpleparser/ChainedProperties.cs?revision=285&view=markup#l136). If you look at it you'll see that it first looks for a value that ends with `pt` such as `12pt`. If it finds that then it drops the `pt` and parses the number literally. If it doesn't end with `pt` it jumps over to [`HtmlUtilities`](http://itextsharp.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/itextsharp/trunk/src/core/iTextSharp/text/html/HtmlUtilities.cs?revision=285&view=markup) to a method called [`GetIndexedFontSize()`](http://itextsharp.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/itextsharp/trunk/src/core/iTextSharp/text/html/HtmlUtilities.cs?revision=285&view=markup#l295). This method is expecting either values like `+1` and `-1` for relative sizes or just integers like `2` for indexed sizes. Per the [HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/graphics.html#adef-size-FONT) user agents are supposed to accept values 1 through 7 for the font size and map those to a progressively increasing font size list. What this means is that your value of `9f` is actually not a valid value to pass to this, you should probably be passing `9pt` instead.

Anyway, you kind of half to jump around in the source to figure out what's being parsed where.

Comment: Thanks Chris.. what are the possible values of these various properties. any tutorials..